# How do I enforce a key of an object to be of a certain type?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a function that can take a generic objects key and use that to create a function to sort string properties using `String.localCompare` but I can't get TypeScript to understand that `a[key]` and `b[key]` are supposed to be strings.

How do I enforce this in TS?

```
const makeStringSort = <T>(key: keyof T) => {
  return (a: T, b: T) => {
    return a[key].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[key].toLowerCase());
  };
};
```

```
Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'T[keyof T]'
```

---

```
// example usage

interface Item {
  prop: string;
  other: number;
}
const sortFn = makeStringSort<Item>("prop");
const items: Item[] = [];
items.sort(sortFn);
```

Comment: TypeScript does not have any information about the values of type `T`. `a[key]` is such a value and it may be of any type. Let `T extend Record<string, string>` and it will stop complaining (because in that case `a[key]` is a `string`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer: use mapped types

```
const makeStringSort = <T extends string>(key: T) => {
  return <
    U extends {
      [Property in T]: string;
    }
  >(
    a: U,
    b: U
  ) => {
    return a[key].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[key].toLowerCase());
  };
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've updated the question with an example since it was not clear what I wanted.

Comment: @hornta updated answer, does this work?

Comment: Cool, it does. I had to provide the prop to sort by as a generic as well so it feels a bit redundant: makeStringSort<"prop", Item>("prop"). I accept this as the answer. Do you think it will be possible not to have to specify "prop" two times?

Comment: @hornta yes, updated answer

Comment: Thanks, I like how it became reusable for different entities with same properties, it didn't occur to me I could do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Reading your code seems that key is a subtype of string and `a` and `b` are `Record<string, string>`.

```js
const makeStringSort = <T extends Record<string, string>>(key: keyof T) => {
  return (a: T, b: T) => {
    return a[key].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[key].toLowerCase());
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this doesn't work as in my example:

Type 'Item' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string, string>'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Item'.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a helper:

```
type KeysOfType<O, T> = {
  [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends T ? K : never;
}[keyof O];
```

to extract the keys of `O` that have a value of type `T`, then you can use it to constrain your function:

```
const makeStringSort = <T>(key: KeysOfType<T, string>) => {
  return <TV extends { [K in KeysOfType<T, string>]: string }>(a: TV, b: TV) => {
    return a[key].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[key].toLowerCase());
  };
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcDyAzAKuCAeJAaKaAfFALxQDeAUFFANoxQCWAdlANbwD2KUSAugC5e9PlAgAPYBGYATBASgB+WFCHMIANwgAnANyUAvrQ4huvPvsoBjTswTAoAWwCGHAMrBtLAOZvO2hzIsIgAKEyE4RFQMSGD8ey9mb0IASlJiKhptCGAAV21WYIA1MUlpOQo6BhZYeGR0TDioBJ9CQWbPHygDQhDnITQi-AAjAaK0kgzqGihsvIKoZ2N4PgA6YE4AGU4Adx0AYWcECBCU1YAbTitnc4h9zkcwZ2yQ4eWQNY3tve1D49OUvoaAZ9CDKJRQJAoAAxTicUgUab9DqJby4aZWIQtJLomijKDMXKOYY6UHg8E2OwOBD+KTaBEudydJJ+AJYWGcXoAImcXJSlAA9AKZlAAHqKCm2exQFBwgCMQg5CPIiyEXJkXPwmKgXKsVk1UHxcu61ilDllnAATIq4crVTrhgbtVzvK6DfjLSbTVTZhAELlzoFmrSdCELXL8BbLSkgA)